# Quartz @DisallowConcurrentExecution not working as expected

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am using java quartz schedular. I am able to schedule jobs perfectly, though what i want is wait for job to finish before runing the second round because the time it takes to run each job varies.

I used @DisallowConcurrentExecution, what it did is only make the job to run once and never again. From job listener shows that the job finished successfully once.

```
Job
=============================================================

@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class SalesJob implements Job{
    List<Transaction> unsentTransaction = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
    List<Sale> sales = new ArrayList<Sale>();

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jec) throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("Sales Job. . .");
    }
}
```

Job Listener:

```
public class SalesJobListener implements JobListener{
public static final String LISTENER_NAME = "dummyJobListenerName";

public String getName() {
    return LISTENER_NAME;
}

public void jobToBeExecuted(JobExecutionContext context) {
    String jobName = context.getJobDetail().getKey().toString();
System.out.println("jobToBeExecuted");
System.out.println("Job : " + jobName + " is going to start...");
}

public void jobExecutionVetoed(JobExecutionContext jec) {
    System.out.println("jobExecutionVetoed");
}

public void jobWasExecuted(JobExecutionContext context, JobExecutionException jobException) {
    System.out.println("jobWasExecuted");
    String jobName = context.getJobDetail().getKey().toString();
    System.out.println("Job : " + jobName + " is finished...");
    System.out.println("=====================================");
    System.out.println("==========" + new Date() + "===========");

    if (!jobException.getMessage().equals("")) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Exception thrown by: " + jobName + " Exception: " + jobException.getMessage());
    }
}

}
```

This is the schedular

```
JobKey salesJobKey = new JobKey("salesJob", "group1");
    JobDetail salesJob = JobBuilder.newJob(SalesJob.class)
    .withIdentity(salesJobKey).build();

    Trigger salesTrigger = TriggerBuilder
                            .newTrigger()
                            .withIdentity("salesTrigger", "group1")
                            .withSchedule(
                                    CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/5 * * * * ?"))
                            .build();

    Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
    scheduler.getListenerManager().addJobListener(
        new SalesJobListener(), KeyMatcher.keyEquals(salesJobKey)
    );

    scheduler.start();
    scheduler.scheduleJob(salesJob, salesTrigger);
```

Comment: do you wait more than a minute? according your schedule cron will run at second `0` and second `5` of each minute but **WILL WAIT UNTIL FINISHED TO LAUNCH ANOTHER JOB**

Comment: it executed this time, Wed Nov 25 12:01:15 EAT 2015 and now is Wed Nov 25 12:32 2015, so basically i have waited > 30 mins. . . and there is no another job

Comment: if it was executed at second 15 means your schedule is not working.

Answer (score 1):

**PROBLEM**

> it executed this time, Wed Nov 25 12:01:15 EAT 2015 and now is Wed Nov 25 12:32 2015, so basically i have waited > 30 mins. . . and there is no another job

That is saying the `Scheduler` is not working.

**WHY?**

- you cannot execute a job at second 15 of a minute because the pattern: `0/5 * * * * ?` makes scheduler to run **ONLY** at seconds 0 and 5 of each minute.
- Using `@DisallowConcurrentExecution` will prevent execution a Job if another one of same type is already running.

---

**SOLUTION:**

The mistake is in the order of your code, you execute then scheduler (`scheduler.start();`) before tell that it must schedule a job (`scheduler.scheduleJob(salesJob, salesTrigger);`):

```
scheduler.start();
scheduler.scheduleJob(salesJob, salesTrigger);
```

Check [this example](https://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/examples/Example3) and swap your lines:

```
scheduler.scheduleJob(salesJob, salesTrigger);
scheduler.start();
```

That's all...

Comment: i swap as you said but no difference. Yes it starts Nov 25 12:55:00 EAT 2015, the essue is even after a minute, its not executed again

Comment: @YunusEinsteinium have you checked link provided? did you have any error creating scheduler?

Comment: With the code i posted above, no i get no error upon when creating scheduler. If i annotate Job implementation class with @DisallowConcurrencyExecution, the job is executed only once, but without this annotation, it execute multiple times

Comment: with Quartz version are you using?

Comment: v 2.1.5, i used this dependacy <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: Its version 2.1.5, any idea why is misbehaiving?

Answer (score 0):

Just Add the below null check

```
if(null != jobException) {
                if (!jobException.getMessage().equals("")) {
                    logger.debug("Exception thrown by: " + jobName
                            + " Exception: " + jobException.getMessage());
                }           
            }
```

Your code will work

Comment: When there is no exception that jobException is null, hence it fails at that point